# % image dimensions and page speed

Tags: html, performance, responsive-design

My new responsive exommerce site is fluid and is using % image dimensions for our product results page, which loads in content via a web service post-DOM load. As I can't specify dimensions, it's causing reflows and repaints as every product image downloads. I wont know up-front how many products will be returned. I'd like to make the page snappier, any good ideas?

I thought about working out the pixel dimensions in JS, then set those dimensions on a lightweight blank placeholder image in place of the product images, then doing a second pass changing over the img src, but retaining the dimensions. Would this prevent reflowing the render tree?

Comment: isn't faster to start with fixed size and in js to switch to %?

Comment: HA! Talk about not seeing the wood for the trees! Sounds like the right approach. Just need to test if that then causes one reflow/repaint when the % os applied. I can handle one, its the multiple reflows/repaints that annoy me. Thanks.

Comment: Although... I'd need to change the size to % by iterating through a collection of objects, I wonder if each iteration would cause a re-paint. I could take it out of the render tree but I then lose progressive loading of the products